# Set value on propertygrid combobox (jeasyui)

Tags: jquery-easyui

How to set value on jeasyui combobox inside propertygrid using jquery?

I tried to fire the grid using a selector, and then select the "td" where the combobox is generated, but without success.
The value of the "td" changes, but when you click on the combobox or make a post the original previous value returns

```
   $("#datagrid-row-r4-2-3 > td:nth-child(3) > div").html('new value');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, follow the code:

```
//update visual value on screen
$("#datagrid-row-r4-2-3 > td:nth-child(3) > div").html(row.cd_erro);
//update value
$("#pg").propertygrid('getRows')[3].value = 'new value';
```